# MVC IE8 with Chrome Frame double post when return csv file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create and return a CSV file from a controller but I have several errors in IE8 with Chrome frame, because the controller returns a file and again calls post two times.

In my view I have a simple submit button:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult File()
        {
            string billcsv = "account_ref,line1,line2,line3";
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(billcsv);
            string filename = "billfor.csv";

            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition();
            cd.FileName = "filename.csv";
            //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.csv");

            return File(data, "text/csv", filename);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? I don't think you need the AddHeader, the return File should take care of it.

Comment: Does this happen in just IE 8 or in the Chrome browser (not frame plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public FileResult File()
{
    string billcsv = "account_ref,line1,line2,line3";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(billcsv);
    string filename = "billfor.csv";

    File(data, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i try this code and the result is same :( When create the file ie8 open the popup and in this moment generate the second post... I didnt found any solution...

Comment: Can you post your code in your View (cshtml)? It shouldn't be posting a second time.